# Why do my questions get downvoted?

Tags: discussion

Someone is going through my questions serially down-voting several in a row with no comment and explanation.  Given this is a well-known pattern could the down-voters *please* take the time to say *why* . The site is starved for new questions and new users and questions getting closed hurts this imho

and yes this is meta.  i will close it shortly assuming it doesn't get down-voted out in seconds which is also possible.

Comment: I think the system will in theory revert those downvotes at some point, but I seem to recall reading you can flag questions you feel have been serially downvoted if that doesn't happen.

Comment: To answer your title question more generally, I generally downvote and vote to close questions when it's clear the OP put zero effort into writing or researching it, or the site, and I feel from past experience that it would be a waste of time to try explaining why. Mostly I use downvoting as a signal to other regular users to not waste time on junk questions, which unfortunately we seem to get a lot of. However, I try to be good about _retracting_ downvotes and/or voting to reopen when the OP comes back and makes improvements, but we get a lot of "eats, shoots, and leaves" users...

Comment: ...that ask a question and then are never heard from again, even when they're asked for clarification.

Comment: Classic example: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/32627/print-error-in-line-17

Comment: That is helpful.  thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do definitely see the 3 in a row recently which is abnormal.

Individual votes cannot be traced back to a user, even by moderators. The dev team probably could, but for a small case like this they wouldn't.

I've run what analysis I do have and can say that no single person has engaged in a major downvote campaign against you. One person did have a large number of downvotes against you, but has almost 5x as many upvotes for you, so it's far more likely they just have a lighter downvote trigger than most. (You also represent a very small percentage of that user's downvotes.)

There was another user with a moderate number of downvotes toward you, but this user's statistics show they vote down WAY more than they vote up.

I'm not saying you're not a victim, but you're not a severe enough victim that we can do much about it. I wish there was more I could do, but the thresholds are set to make sure only severe cases get attention.

:shrug: ?